# Calculate CPU% usage from DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I have some droplets in digital ocean and i want to create a dashboard to see the data on my webApp.
This currently the code in my backend:

```
token = MY_TOKEN
client = DropletKit::Client.new(access_token: token)

def generate_timestamps_for_last_hour
 # util function to generate timestamps for last hour
end

current_time, last_hour_time = generate_timestamps_for_last_hour

droplets = client.droplets.all
droplets.each do |droplet|
  host_id = droplet.id

  if (droplet.name == 'main-db')
    puts "Droplet ID: #{host_id}"
    puts "Droplet Name: #{droplet.name}"
    puts "Droplet Status: #{droplet.status}"
    puts "Droplet IPv4 Address: #{droplet.networks.v4[0].ip_address}"
    get_cpu_usage(host_id, last_hour_time, current_time, token)
  end
end
```

And here is the main function to get the data from DigitalOcean:

```
def get_cpu_usage(host_id, start_time, end_time, token)
  uri = URI("https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/monitoring/metrics/droplet/cpu")
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({ host_id: host_id, start: start_time, end: end_time })

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{token}"
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end

  if response.code == '200'
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)

  else
    puts "Failed to fetch droplet metrics. HTTP Error #{response.code}: #{response.message}"
  end
end
```

I get the data but I don't know how to calculate CPU% usage.

this is sample data of it looks like:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "idle"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "836680.1399999999"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "836918.48"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "iowait"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "529.21"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "529.51"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "irq"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "0"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "nice"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "18.490000000000002"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "18.490000000000002"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "softirq"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "24.68"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "24.689999999999998"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "steal"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "102.99000000000001"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "103.00999999999999"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "system"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "759.1199999999999"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "759.5699999999999"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "metric": {
                    "host_id": host_id,
                    "mode": "user"
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        1708955160,
                        "948.6099999999999"
                    ],
                    [
                        1708955280,
                        "949.23"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a separate CPU percentage metrics API endpoint: https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/monitoring_get_appCPUPercentageMetrics